# Can I determine if app was installed via Facebook Ad?

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

Is there a way to determine if the currently running app was installed via Facebook ad?

I am currently calling [FBAppEvent activateApp] in my app delegate's applicationDidBecomeActive selector.  I'm not using any other Facebook SDK features.

I would like to distinguish users that arrived via a Facebook ad.  Is there any way on the phone to determine that an app installation came from a Facebook ad?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm looking for the same information.

Comment: nothing yet and I have moved on to other things, but I'll probably get back to it eventually.

Comment: I also want to do this.  I want to to track this so we can use this data with our engagement and activation metrics.

Comment: I just can give you the advice to post it as a `bug` at facebook. So you'll get an answer within 12-24hrs. They tell you how it works or that they'll take it on their feature wish list ;) https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/created/

Comment: @Jurik Thanks for the link!  I will post it as a bug on Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the response I got from Facebook developer support on this issue.

Unfortunately this is not currently possible using the SDK. As per the docs, we only send information on when someone installs the app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads
"After installing the SDK, include the following code to be executed when your app is in the foreground. This will allow the app to ping back the install event to Facebook when the user opens up the app for the first time, and again in the future if there is a network error. Our client code will stop sending installs once it acquires a success code from the server, and our back-end will only count the install a single time if it receives multiple hits for the same device"

I hope this helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. It isn't as easy as you would hope, but this is what you do.

1. Look in your logs on your server to see when someone's clicked through an ad
2. Find the IP address connected to that request I.E 8.8.8.8 (Google OpenDNS, if you're wondering).
3. look for the same IP address of someone who accesses the page after they've installed the app. If you find a match, your ad worked.
4. write a python script or have me write a python script to do this automatically.